# RNCSafeAreaView was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

System:
OS: Linux 5.3 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz
Memory: 378.16 MB / 7.66 GB
Shell: 4.4.20 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 12.16.1 - /usr/bin/node
Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman

**SDKs:**

- Android SDK:
- API Levels: 23, 25, 27, 28
- Build Tools: 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
- System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google
  APIs Intel x86 Atom

**IDEs:**
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312

npmPackages:

react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0

react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5

npmGlobalPackages:

react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4"
  }
```

code:

```
function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `react-native-safe-area-view`

reference https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view#in-bare-react-native-projects